# How can I remove the last line of a file using php?

Tags: php

I've tried a lot of potential solutions, but none of them are working for me.
The simplest one:

```
$file = file('list.html');
array_pop($file);
```

isn't doing anything at all. Am I doing something wrong here? Is it different because it's an html file?

Comment: Please give some more details

Comment: You'd need to write $file back to list.html for that to actually change the file stored on disk

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the last line and save it back to disk?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work :

```
<?php 

// load the data and delete the line from the array 
$lines = file('filename.txt'); 
$last = sizeof($lines) - 1 ; 
unset($lines[$last]); 

// write the new data to the file 
file_put_contents('filename.txt', $lines);
```

Comment: I read that on another site, but when I tried it, it copied the original document and everything appeared twice. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I figured out what I was doing wrong and it was really stupid. I was trying write the array to the file and append the new information simultaneously. I needed to fopen('list.html', 'w+'); then close, then open it again with 'a'. Thanks for all the help though! This solution does work.

Comment: How do we remove the first and last lines from the CSV @angezanetti ?

Comment: 1. you will lose all ilne breaks in file 2. ou will store whole file in 1 variable

Comment: 3. `unset($var[count($var) - 1])` is less elegant than `array_pop($var)` and 4. Empty glue does not need to be declared when imploding. (`$implode($lines)`)

Answer (score 1):

I created a function to remove x number of lines from the bottom. Set `$max` to the number of lines you want to delete.

```
function trim_lines($path, $max) { 
  // Read the lines into an array
  $lines = file($path);
  // Setup counter for loop
  $counter = 0;
  while($counter < $max) {
    // array_pop removes the last element from an array
    array_pop($lines);
    // Increment the counter
    $counter++;
  }  // End loop
  // Write the trimmed lines to the file
  file_put_contents($path, implode('', $lines));
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
trim_lines("filename.txt", 1);
```

The variable `$path` can be a path to the file or a filename.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple case, I use the following code:

```
$text = file_get_contents( 'FILE_PATH' );
$pos = strrpos( $text, PHP_EOL );
$text = substr( $text, 0, $pos );
file_put_contents( 'FILE_PATH', $text );
```

Or a slightly extended version to check if the file ends with a line break:

```
$text = file_get_contents( 'FILE_PATH' );
$offset = mb_substr( $text, -1 ) == PHP_EOL ? -2 : 0;
$pos = strrpos( $text, PHP_EOL, $offset );
$text = $offset === 0 ? substr( $text, 0, $pos ) : substr( $text, 0, $pos ) . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents( 'FILE_PATH', $text );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove first and last line of a variable in PHP:**

Using phpsh interactive shell:

```
php> $test = "line one\nline two\nline three\nline four";

php> $test = substr($test, (strpos($test, "\n")+1));

php> $test = substr($test, 0, strrpos($test, "\n"));

php> print $test;
line two
line three
```

**You might have meant "The last non blank line".  In that case do this:**

Notice that there are three blank lines after the content.  This gets rid of those lines before removing the last:

```
php> $test = "line one\nline two\nline three\nline four\n\n\n";

php> $test = substr($test, 0, strrpos(trim($test), "\n"));

php> print $test;
line one
line two
line three
```

Answer (score -3):

You are only reading the file, you now need to write the file

Look into [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) etc

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have used more details. I'm asking this question on a different computer than the one I'm writing the code on, so I didn't include everything. I wrote to the file, but it's just not doing anything.