# Delete last line from text file PHP using ftruncate

Tags: php

I am trying to delete last line from my text file in PHP using ftruncate, but the problem is the length if line will keep varying most of the times. And I dont want to use file_put_contents, so that I write the file again because the file could be in Megabytes.

Please any suggestions ?

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381767/how-can-i-remove-the-last-line-of-a-file-using-php

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the code and what you tried so far

Comment: Check the file size, seek to the end, read a character, seek back, read again, until you find a new line

Comment: @alex: what if it's a 10Tb file?

Comment: see [remove All lines except first 20 using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410077/remove-all-lines-except-first-20-using-php)

Comment: @zerkms then I'd be wondering why someone is processing a 10Tb file in PHP

Comment: @alex: as soon as it's one last line removal - why not?

Comment: @Satish Sharma: not even close to be duplicate.

Comment: @alex I dont want to write the whole data into file again. Thats why I am trying something with ftruncate so that it deletes only the last line

Comment: @WizKid I am trying to escape looping through lines, else I know this option would be done

Comment: @Deepanshu did you try `fseek()` yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you an idea what I meant something like this:

```
$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'r+');
$pos = filesize('file.txt');
while ($pos > 0) {
    $pos = max($pos - 1024, 0);
    fseek($fp, $pos);
    $tmp = fread($fp, 1024);
    $tmppos = strrpos($tmp, "\n");
    if ($tmppos !== false) {
        ftruncate($fp, $pos + $tmppos);
        break;
    }
}
```

It will read the last 1024 bytes. Find the last newline in that buffer if it exists. If it exists truncate to that position. If is doesn't exists it reads the next 1024 bytes and check them. And so on.

Comment: its perfect but I need to delete on the basis of second last newline instead of last newline. how can I do that ?

Comment: Modify my example to look for the second newline. Or just run the script twice