# parsing an XML file with extra content at the end

Tags: php, xml

Hello Stack Exchange community,

I'm trying to make a Equifax API to get credit information (don't worry the data you see is all dummy data). I'm using their XML input. I am receiving the XML response just fine, but for some god awful reason the equifax developers decided to add some 'extra' content at the end of outside of the XML tags.

This essentially makes the xml un-parseable in php. Is there a way to strip out the extra content at the end?

Here is the XML response. Look after the closing EfxTransmit tag

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EfxTransmit>
<EfxReport requestNumber="1" reportId="USConsumerCreditReport">
<USDecisionPowerExpressReports>
<USDecisionPowerExpressReport subjectType="Subject" multipleNumber="1">
<USMasterHeader>
<CustomerReferenceNumber>EFX QA</CustomerReferenceNumber>
<CustomerNumber>999KI00553</CustomerNumber>
<ECOAInquiryType>I</ECOAInquiryType>
<DateOfRequest format="MM/DD/CCYY">02/23/2017</DateOfRequest>
<EquifaxReferenceNumber>187388032</EquifaxReferenceNumber>
</USMasterHeader>
<USConsumerCreditReport subjectType="Subject" multipleNumber="1">
<USHeader>
<Request>
<CustomerReferenceNumber>EFX QA</CustomerReferenceNumber>
<CustomerNumber>999KI00553</CustomerNumber>
<ConsumerReferralCode>024</ConsumerReferralCode>
<ECOAInquiryType>I</ECOAInquiryType>
<NumberOfMonthsToCountInquiries>Last 24 Months</NumberOfMonthsToCountInquiries>
<NumberOfMonthsToCountDelinquencies>Last 6 Years, 11 Months</NumberOfMonthsToCountDelinquencies>
</Request>
<CreditFile>
<HitCode code="1" description="Hit"/>
<FileSinceDate format="MM/DD/CCYY">04/16/2003</FileSinceDate>
<DateOfLastActivity format="MM/DD/CCYY">01/24/2017</DateOfLastActivity>
<DateOfRequest format="MM/DD/CCYY">02/23/2017</DateOfRequest>
<Identityscans>
<Identityscan code="8" description="Unable to perform telephone validation due to insufficient telephone input"/>
</Identityscans>
<AddressDiscrepancyIndicator>N</AddressDiscrepancyIndicator>
<CreateCode>2</CreateCode>
<FileStatus1>016</FileStatus1>
<FileStatus2>242</FileStatus2>
<FileStatus3>004</FileStatus3>
<BureauCode>244</BureauCode>
</CreditFile>
<Subject>
<SubjectName>
<LastName>DGNNLXZ</LastName>
<FirstName>CHANITA</FirstName>
<MiddleName>S</MiddleName>
</SubjectName>
<SubjectId>
<SubjectSSN>66639074</SubjectSSN>
<DateOfBirth format="MM/DD/CCYY">08/17/1988</DateOfBirth>
</SubjectId>
</Subject>
</USHeader>
<USAddresses>
<USAddress code="CA" description="Current Address">
<ParsedStreetAddress>
<StreetNumber>4338</StreetNumber>
<StreetName>W POTOMAC</StreetName>
<StreetType>AVE</StreetType>
</ParsedStreetAddress>
<City>CHICAGO</City>
<State>IL</State>
<PostalCode>60651</PostalCode>
<DateAddressFirstReported format="MM/CCYY">07/2015</DateAddressFirstReported>
<AddressSource code="T" description="Tape"/>
<DateAddressLastReported format="MM/CCYY">02/2017</DateAddressLastReported>
</USAddress>
<USAddress code="FA" description="Former Address">
<ParsedStreetAddress>
<StreetNumber>1301</StreetNumber>
<StreetName>BRUMMEL</StreetName>
<StreetType>ST APT 8</StreetType>
</ParsedStreetAddress>
<City>EVANSTON</City>
<State>IL</State>
<PostalCode>60202</PostalCode>
<DateAddressFirstReported format="MM/CCYY">04/2015</DateAddressFirstReported>
<AddressSource code="T" description="Tape"/>
<DateAddressLastReported format="MM/CCYY">04/2015</DateAddressLastReported>
</USAddress>
<USAddress code="F2" description="Second Former Address">
<ParsedStreetAddress>
<StreetNumber>1208</StreetNumber>
<StreetName>W JEFFERSON</StreetName>
<StreetType>ST APT C</StreetType>
</ParsedStreetAddress>
<City>SPRINGFIELD</City>
<State>IL</State>
<PostalCode>62702</PostalCode>
<DateAddressFirstReported format="MM/CCYY">06/2014</DateAddressFirstReported>
<AddressSource code="T" description="Tape"/>
<DateAddressLastReported format="MM/CCYY">06/2014</DateAddressLastReported>
</USAddress>
</USAddresses>
<USEmployments>
<USEmployment code="ES" description="Last Reported Employment">
<Occupation>CORRECTION OFF</Occupation>
<Employer>MACON STATE PRISON</Employer>
</USEmployment>
</USEmployments>
<USFICO>
<FICOScore>00650</FICOScore>
<ScoreReasons>
<ScoreReason code="00038" description="Serious delinquency, and derogatory public record or collection filed" number="1"/>
<ScoreReason code="00010" description="Prop of balances to credit limits is too high on bank rev or other rev accts" number="2"/>
<ScoreReason code="00018" description="Number of accounts with delinquency" number="3"/>
<ScoreReason code="00014" description="Length of time accounts have been established" number="4"/>
</ScoreReasons>
<ScoreIndicator code="J" description="FICO Score 5 based on Equifax Data (NF)"/>
</USFICO>
<USIdentificationSSN>
<MDBSubjectSSN>666390749</MDBSubjectSSN>
<InquirySubjectSSN>666390749</InquirySubjectSSN>
<InquirySSNDateIssued>1992</InquirySSNDateIssued>
<InquirySSNStateIssued>GA</InquirySSNStateIssued>
</USIdentificationSSN>
</USConsumerCreditReport>
<USDecisionPowerExpressSegment>
<ConsumerDisclosureIndicator></ConsumerDisclosureIndicator>
<ReportTextMessage>OFFER C</ReportTextMessage>
<SSNVarianceIndicator></SSNVarianceIndicator>
<DPExpressProducts>
<DPExpressProduct number="1">
<Description>A</Description>
<ApprovalIndicator>N</ApprovalIndicator>
<Limit></Limit>
<Miscellaneous></Miscellaneous>
</DPExpressProduct>
<DPExpressProduct number="2">
<Description>B</Description>
<ApprovalIndicator>N</ApprovalIndicator>
<Limit></Limit>
<Miscellaneous></Miscellaneous>
</DPExpressProduct>
<DPExpressProduct number="3">
<Description>C</Description>
<ApprovalIndicator>Y</ApprovalIndicator>
<Limit></Limit>
<Miscellaneous></Miscellaneous>
</DPExpressProduct>
<DPExpressProduct number="4">
<Description>D</Description>
<ApprovalIndicator>N</ApprovalIndicator>
<Limit></Limit>
<Miscellaneous></Miscellaneous>
</DPExpressProduct>
</DPExpressProducts>
</USDecisionPowerExpressSegment>
</USDecisionPowerExpressReport>
</USDecisionPowerExpressReports>
<USPrintImage><![CDATA[TRANSACTION NUMBER: 187388032
BRANCH NUMBER: EFX QA


NO SUBSTANTIAL DIFFERENCE WAS FOUND BETWEEN INQUIRY ADDRESS(ES) AND 
THE EXISTING CREDIT FILE ADDRESS(ES).


Product         Approval        Limit           Misc            
                Indicator       
C               Y                                               

OFFER C

****  Credit Report Information  ****************************************
Equifax Information Services LLC
P O Box 740241, Atlanta, GA 30374-0241
800/685-1111



Name: CHANITA S DGNNLXZ  Since: 04162003  SSN: 66639074
DOB/Age: 08/17/1988   Last Activity: 01242017    Report Date: 02232017
      072015  4338 W POTOMAC AVE, CHICAGO IL 60651
      042015  1301 BRUMMEL ST APT 8, EVANSTON IL 60202
      062014  1208 W JEFFERSON ST APT C, SPRINGFIELD IL 62702

Employment information: 
 MACON STATE PRISON,   CORRECTION OFF

Identity Scan: UNABLE TO PERFORM TELEPHONE VALIDATION DUE TO INSUFFICIENT TELEPHONE INPUT.

Customer Reference: EFX QA

ADI: NO SUBSTANTIAL DIFFERENCE WAS FOUND BETWEEN INQUIRY ADDRESS(ES) AND 
THE EXISTING CREDIT FILE ADDRESS(ES).


FICO Score 5-EFX-N: 00650               00038 00010 00018 00014   Reject:  
 Serious delinquency, and derogatory public record or collection filed
 Prop of balances to credit limits is too high on bank rev or other rev accts
 Number of accounts with delinquency
 Length of time accounts have been established

END OF REPORT
]]>
</USPrintImage>
</EfxReport>
</EfxTransmit>
FULLEFX QA              999KI005530241I02  1041620030124201702232017DGNNLXZ                  CHANITA        S                66639074 08171988           0010101000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000010000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000N    I     2016242004244 8CA4338      W POTOMAC                 AVE                       CHICAGO             IL60651    072015 T022017                               FA1301      BRUMMEL                   ST APT 8                  EVANSTON            IL60202    042015 T042015                               F21208      W JEFFERSON               ST APT C                  SPRINGFIELD         IL62702    062014 T062014                               ESCORRECTION OFF                     MACON STATE PRISON                                                       CP0065000038000100001800014          J  SS  666390749            6663907491992GA          DP A    N               B    N               C    Y               D    N
```

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381767/how-can-i-remove-the-last-line-of-a-file-using-php) referring to deleting the last line of a file. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624664/simple-php-function-to-remove-the-last-line-from-text-file-not-working) might help too.

Comment: Glad to help :)